# Kiosk mode for FireFox 4.0 on execute

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-3.0-honeycomb, firefox4

I have an Acer iconia a500 with Android 3.1, FireFox 4.0 installed (for websockets and other HTML5 goodies).  I need to run FF in a Kiosk mode for our application.

Even better if someone out there has figured out how to run Chrome on Android.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to run FF in a Kiosk mode for our application.

Android does not have a "kiosk mode".

The closest thing you will have in Android to a "kiosk mode" is to write your own home screen app. However, Firefox Mobile is not set up to be a home screen app for Android.

> Even better if someone out there has figured out how to run Chrome on Android.

There is no Chrome for Android.

Comment: Now there is a Chrome for Android.